# mistake in post method

Tags: php, jquery

So mistake in POST, I tried sent the variable login thought load, but when I tried receive it in sea.php it is give me mistake.

js code :

```
$(document).on('click','#sea_submit', function () {
    var login = $("input[name=log]").val();
    if (login != "")
    {
        $("#din_content").load("sea.php", {login:login});
        return false;
    }
});
```

php code:

```
$login=stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['login'])); //mistake here
// I tried  and like that $login = $_POST['login'];
if ((isset($login)) && (!empty($login)))
{
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Login='$login'",$db);
    if (empty($result))
    {
        printf("The user with login=".$login." not found");
    }
    else 
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_result($result);
       //code
    }
}
```

Html code:

```
<form>
 <div id="sea_cr_login">
        <h2 class="sea_names">Login:</h2>
        <div>
            <div class="sea_labels">                        
                <label class="sea_var">Login:</label>
                <input class="sea_ch" name="log" type="text" maxlength="16" size="10">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
    <div id="sea_sub">
        <input type="submit" value="sea" id="sea_submit">
    </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: And this mistake is...? You are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: WAIT! Are you saying the code you originally posted was wrong?

Comment: yes , but now is correct, But still mistake is there

Comment: What is the mistake?

Comment: POST http://localhost/fold/sea.php [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 1ms]

Comment: That means there is something wrong with your PHP. Is that *all* of the PHP in the file?

Comment: actually no there is another 300 lines, but as soon I delete this line $login=stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['login'])); it is works without mistakes

Comment: There is *nothing* wrong with that line outside of a best practices issue. Change the line to `$login = $_POST['login'];` just to test.

Comment: yes, the same mistake, if I put this line in comment everything work, also you sad that is not a best way to do it, what will be the best way? if I have one page and the jquery alway load content that user need.

Comment: post your HTML form. If you feel it's not part of the problem, great. Otherwise, we don't know if your syntax is correct. @alex_mike

Comment: You're too far removed from best practice at this point. Try this instead - `$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);` and comment out everything below the line to make sure this line works. using this function *is much better than* what you're doing now.

Comment: yes I'm sure, I'm make alert(login); in Jquery that make sure that it is works

Comment: using $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']); it doesn't give me any mistake

Comment: Hallelujah! now you can start uncommenting other code until you find the error.

Comment: also is it ok using structure of web site as one page with jquery that loaded content, instead creating 10 pages and move one to another?

Comment: Sure, there is no problem with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80106/discussion-between-alex-mike-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: is this question still considered open? or has the answer below solved it? I don't see a green ticky, so this tells us that the question is still open/unsolved. @alex_mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have (prior to the OP's edit) mis-matched variable names. You're sending `login_sch` so you have to change this line:

```
$login=stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['login_sch'])); //mistake here
```

Ideally you should change the line to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` as it is much more effective than the two nested functions you have now:

```
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
```

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) which needs to be fixed as soon as possible.

If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

If you're set on building your own login system you should start with having the proper basics in place - [Use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: I'm sorry but it was my mistake when I create the post in login_sch, even if it is will be a login it will make me mistake